# IHttpActionResult in MVC not firing from angular.js $http.post method

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, angularjs, asp.net-web-api

i have angular.js code like this :

```
(function (appAN) {
    'use strict';
    appAN.controller('InfoController', function ($scope, $http) {
        $scope.model = {
            firstname: "john",
            lastname: "doe",
            company: 'IBM',
        }
        $scope.addbtn = function () {
            var info = {
                firstname: $scope.model.firstname,
                lastname: $scope.model.lastname,
                company: $scope.model.company
            }
            var url = "Info/AddInfo";
            var data = JSON.stringify(info);
            $http.post(url, data).success(function (data) {
                alert(success);
            });
        }
    });
}(angular.module('testd',[])));
```

and in c# code like this :

```
namespace testdemo.Controllers
{
    public class InfoController : ApiController
    {
        [HttpPost]
        public IHttpActionResult AddInfo([FromBody]InfoClass info)
        {
            object o = new object();
            return Json(o);
        }
    }

    public class InfoClass
    {
        public string firstname { get; set; }
        public string lastname { get; set; }
        public string company { get; set; }
    }
}
```

now problem is : i am not able to get values in my c# method, breaking point is not hitting also at 'AddInfo' method.

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404
>   (Not Found) http://localhost:63498/Info/AddInfo

i am able to see the values untill :  `var data = JSON.stringify(info);`

what is wrong with my code ?

my routing is like this :

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
             name: "DefaultApi",
             routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
             defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
         );
        config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SupportedMediaTypes.Add(new MediaTypeHeaderValue("text/html"));
    }
}
```

Comment: 1.Could you please tell what you are doing in the post method? 2. Did you check the api whether it's working or not in the fiddler or any rest client? 3. Try adding the url as "api/Info/AddInfo"

Comment: yes, i got error as not found 404 !, did i miss routing information for my ApiController?

Comment: You should look into webapiconfig.cs

Comment: call api as follows in the fillder.                                                                            http://localhost:63498/api/Info/AddInfo

Comment: same thing, not able to fix.

Comment: ok, can anyone provide sample example of IHttpActionResult with custom method name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should register your routes for ApiControllers in App_Start/WebApiConfig.cs. Something like this:

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );

    }
}
```

And then use url like this:

```
var url = "/api/Info/AddInfo";
```

Answer (score 0):

remove JSON.stringify from your code and directly pass info object in your $http.post. Angular will stringify it for you :)

You need to annotate your post handler for a rest end.

Add you post URL in RouteConfig

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have the following snippet in the webapiconfig.cs to call webapi.

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );
            config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SupportedMediaTypes.Add(new MediaTypeHeaderValue("text/html"));
```

Mention api url as follows in the "**api/Info/AddInfo**"

Comment: OK, i did exactly same !  and error i got it is : 'POST http://localhost:63498/api/Info/AddInfo 404 (Not Found)'

Comment: did you do the changes in the webapiconfig.cs file.looks like you are using the MVC stuff over there.